# How do I abort an upload to Google Drive?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am using the following sample to upload a file to Google Drive. How do I abort the upload? I have tried setting `xhr.abort()`, after setting an `xhr` variable to `null` in the constructor.

```
var MediaUploader = function (options) {
    var noop = function () { };
    this.file = options.file;
    this.contentType = options.contentType || this.file.type || 'application/octet-stream';
    this.metadata = options.metadata || {
        'title': this.file.name,
        'mimeType': this.contentType
    };
    this.token = options.token;
    this.onComplete = options.onComplete || noop;
    this.onProgress = options.onProgress || noop;
    this.onError = options.onError || noop;
    this.offset = options.offset || 0;
    this.chunkSize = options.chunkSize || 0;
    this.retryHandler = new RetryHandler();
    this.xhr = null;
    this.url = options.url;
    if (!this.url) {
        var params = options.params || {};
        params.uploadType = 'resumable';
        this.url = this.buildUrl_(options.fileId, params, options.baseUrl);
    }
    this.httpMethod = options.fileId ? 'PUT' : 'POST';
};
MediaUploader.prototype.Cancel= function()
{
    this.xhr.abort();
}
```

https://github.com/googledrive/cors-upload-sample

Well actually if you see the code [here](https://github.com/googledrive/cors-upload-sample/blob/master/upload.js).

That `xhr` is not a class variable; it is always created using another instance each time a different function is called for example if you see:

```
MediaUploader.prototype.upload = 
    function() { 
        var self = this; 
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    };
```

So what I have done is moved that `xhr` to a class variable, so that it will be not null at the time I call `uploader.Cancel`.  After those changes code becomes like this:

```
MediaUploader.prototype.upload = 
    function() { 
        var self = this; 
        this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    };
```

I changed the code for all functions and used `this.xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();` where its creating `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();` but that's not working.  I am still unable to cancel upload..

Comment: so on button click i want to abort current upload. is that possible?

Comment: Fixed English grammar errors and improved readability.

Comment: Part of your problem may be that you're setting `this.xhr = null;`, then your cancel function tries to call `this.xhr.abort();`, while `this.xhr` is still null (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @Jim L thanksfor your reply and please sorry for my grammar i am not a native english speeker.

Comment: well actually if you see the code here https://github.com/googledrive/cors-upload-sample/blob/master/upload.js

Comment: that xhr is not a class vairable it always created using another instance each time a different function is called for example if you see
"MediaUploader.prototype.upload = function() {
  var self = this;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();"


 so what i have done is moved that xhr to class variable. so that will be not null at the time i call uploader.Cancel. so after those changes code becomes like this  "MediaUploader.prototype.upload = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();"

Comment: i changed the code for all functions and used this.xhr where its creating " var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" but thats not working. i am still unable to cancel upload..